# Switching String to Integer

Tags: java, if-statement, syntax, switch-statement

*I need the syntax for adding in the variable parameter to a switch case that already has lots of parameters. The context is provided below.*

I'm using a switch case to change a string answer to an integer return. Instead of having the user answer 
1. This.
 
2. Something else.
I want the answer to look like
(y/n)

I've done it before with a code like this:

```
static public int getYN() {
    String answer = "";
    switch(keyboard.nextLine().substring(0, 1).toLowerCase()) {
        case "y":
            return 1;

        case "n":
            return 0;

        default:
            return 2;

    }
}
```

And then using the statement:

```
int getAnswer = getYN();
        System.out.println();

        if (getAnswer == 1) {
        System.out.println("Stuff.");
        test = 1;
        }
        else {
        System.out.println("Other stuff."); 
        System.out.println();
    }
```

But, I don't know where to put the String answer variable into the switch case. Usually, if you aren't using many other parameters, it would just be

```
 switch(answer) {
}
```

Comment: Please add correct language tag... Looks like [tag:java]

Comment: Please add specific question...

Comment: Question is not clear. What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: Edited above. Basically, without the string variable "answer" in the switch case, it isn't doing anything, but I'm not quite sure how to add that variable into the parameters (and I've idiotically tried something like switch(answer.keyboard.nextLine().etc) {}.

Comment: You mean like `switch (x) { case y: ... case z: ... }`? You can't do that. Maybe instead you mean you want to switch on strings? That should be fine as long as you're using Java 7+.

Comment: To simplify, are you trying to generate a method of having code `return 1;` when given the input `y` and `return 0;` when given input `n` or something more expansive and generalized?

Comment: Yes, @TheCapn, so the user will be able to use a yes/no answer, rather than a 1/2 answer. It was pretty simple the first time I did it, and then I forgot the syntax.

Comment: Why not do something more simple like capturing the input in String then `return "y".equalsIgnoreCase(answer);` where you'll get a true/false boolean return value.

Comment: How is you're code messing up? It looks fine to me. Maybe you could switch on keyboard....toCharArray()[0] if using java <7

Comment: That makes a lot more sense. Where would that be used in context, though? The if-else, or switch-statement (or would there be no switch statement at all)?

Comment: Dude, thanks. I knew there was a specific way to get character answers.

Answer (score 0):

Check it inline, forget having a dedicated method to doing this check.

```
    char getAnswer = keyboard.next().charAt(0);

    System.out.println();

    if (getAnswer == 'y' || getAnswer == 'Y') 
    {
        System.out.println("Stuff.");
        test = 1;
    }
    else if( getAnswer == 'n' || getAnswer == 'N')
    {
        System.out.println("Other stuff."); 
        System.out.println();
    }
```

If you absolutely have to use a switch:

```
    char getAnswer = keyboard.next().charAt(0);

    switch(getAnswer)
    {
        case 'y':
          System.out.println("Stuff.");
          test = 1;
          break;
        case 'n':
          System.out.println("Other stuff."); 
          System.out.println();
          break;
    }
```

Comment: I found that the code `if(answer.equalsIgnoreCase("yes")) {}` or `("no")` works for this same thing, and I'm not sure how it took me this long to figure it out. But, these answers work as well, and it's good material for coding logic. Thanks! Especially the answer from @Bohemian.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve the same thing in one line:

```
public static int getYN(String s) {
    return ("yn YN".indrxOf(s) + 3) % 3;
}
```

Both upper and lower cases are handled, and the "not found" default value of 2 is handled by adding 3 (`indexOf()` returns `-1` when the target is not found) and modulus divusion takes care of the capital letter indexes.

Fairly neat even if I do say so myself.